# log4j in java project displays wrong file when clicking on link from Conversion Character

Tags: java, log4j

I created a Java 6 project in Eclipse that uses log4j to output debug info to the console.  We'll call this Project1.  No problem.  Then I copied the entire contents of the folder into a new folder (apparently, not a good idea).  Then, I Imported Existing Project into Workspace.  We'll call that Project2.  When I run Project2, I see my debug statement's output to the console.  I used a ConversionPattern that included (%F:%L) so I could click on the link and Eclipse will take me to that file and line number.
The problem is: when I click on the link in the console, Eclipse takes me to the file in Project1, not Project2.  I obviously got some wires crossed when I created Project2 by copying Project1.  The only way around this (so far) is to rename the class file that has the logger.debug statements.  I would rather fix the bigger problem.  I have Googled this and looked through the log4j posts on this site, but can't find a solution.  Below is the log4j.properties file.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R
# log4j.rootLogger=error, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=RevIC.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=500KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Comment: Use %l instead of (%F:%L) pattern

Comment: Used %l instead.  Got 'Source not found...' when clicking on the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ( %l). The space before the % is required because it will try to add the open paren to the link.

Comment: %l made no difference.  Getting a much longer link with package and class info, but still opening wrong file in Project1.

Comment: %l worked after all.  I was not putting the space before the percent sign.    'code'   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %l - %m%n